# Error con validación de solo números en Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

He visto varias soluciones que ofrecen en este sitio pero la verdad no sé cómo adaptar la solución que les dan a otros usuarios a mi código. El problema es con un Código de JS el cual me debe verificar que en un campo de texto solo se ingresen números, les anexo los códigos:

```js
function ValidaSoloNumeros() {
    if ((event.keyCode < 48) || (event.keyCode > 57))
        event.returnValue = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1" onkeypress="ValidaSoloNumeros();">
```

Sucede que en **Google Chrome** el código funciona a la perfección, pero en **Mozilla Firefox** no, es decir, puedo ingresar texto también, les agradezco por adelantado la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y puedas mejorar tu pregunta y que se entienda más. No entiendo bien tu pregunta, ¿puedes poner más código? Dices que el problema es verificar un campo de texto y el código que has puesto son eventos de teclado.

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación, pero no entiendo porque no aparece el código de HTML, reviso el post y está ahi pero al publicarlo no aparece, no entiendo. Lo dejaré por acá. <input type="text" id="n1" onkeypress="ValidaSoloNumeros();">

Comment: Entonces...como soluciono el problema? no soy muy avanzado en JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para obtener el evento normalmente se utiliza **`event`** , **firefox** no!, para firefox es **`e`**, por lo tanto realizaremos un pequeño cambio para esto

```js
function ValidaSoloNumeros() {
var e = e || window.event;
    if ((e.keyCode < 48) || (e.keyCode > 57)){
        e.returnValue = false;
    e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1" onkeypress="ValidaSoloNumeros();">
```

asi mismo tienes un error a evitar la propagacion del evento puedes ver mas 
 en la documentacion [**`Event.preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Otro ejemplo usando listeners

```js
n1.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  const e = event;

     if (isNaN(parseFloat(e.key))){
         e.returnValue = false;
          e.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1" >
```

**ADICIONAL**
puedes usar el manejo de evento con [Listener](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/110972/28035) , en ambas opciones es javascript puro

Comment: Si explicaras lo que hace el metodo preventDefault() con un poco mas de detalles, te sacas la loteria.

Comment: Muchas gracias, resuelto el problema, investigaré mas sobre los nuevos elementos del código para documentarme mejor.

Comment: El código no funciona al ejecutar en Stack Snippet y Firefox 57 para Windows 64-bit. El error que indica es "TypeError: e is undefined"

Comment: voy a actualizar mi respuesta y agregar por listener

Comment: por alguna razon dejo de funcionar supongo una actualizacion de firefox, con esta forma es valida para chrome y firefox