# Como capturar un texto o numero que ha sido ingresado a una caja de texto en JS

Tags: javascript

Al usuario ingresar un texto o numero ¿como puedo lo puedo capturar y almacenarlo en una variable?

He estado probando con :

```js
let captureNumber = document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML;

console.log(captureNumber)
```

```html
 <input type="number" placeholder="Nivel de Seguridad"  min="65" max="90" id="number2">
```

Lo que intento hacer ahi es que al usuario seleccionar un numero sea capturado y ese numero ser mostrado en consola.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error con validación de solo números en Firefox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/113005/error-con-validaci%c3%b3n-de-solo-n%c3%bameros-en-firefox)

Comment: @JackNavaRow  no tiene nada que ver con mi pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu ejercicio faltan dos cosas, un disparador del evento que va a ejecutar la función de capturar el valor y capturar realmente el valor:

En este caso usaremos el evento `onchange` que se ejecuta cuando un elemento de formulario cambia su valor.

Una vez que hayamos detectado el cambio de valor procedemos a capturar el valor, el cual en elementos de formulario de captura con `.value` y no con `.innerHTML` como lo intentabas hacer.

```js
function cambioValor(){
  let captureNumber = document.getElementById("number2").value

  console.log(captureNumber)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Nivel de Seguridad"  min="65" max="90" id="number2" onchange="cambioValor();">
```

Comment: ¿y como puedo capturar ese numero  y almacenarlo en una variable?

Comment: @user889 ya lo estás capturando y almacenando en la variable captureNumber

Comment: gracias @Bender

Comment: de hecho el onchange funciona en firefox cuando abandono la caja de texto , les invito a probarlo

Comment: @JackNavaRow acabo de probarlo en Firefox y funciona igual con las flechas, será algo de versiones?

Comment: @JackNavaRow en mi navegador chrome no me funciona tu ejemplo, no me captura el valor actual captura el valor anterior

Answer (score 0):

Tienes muchas opciones, colocare dos de ellas:

**Con [OnKeyPress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)**

```js
const $number2 = document.getElementById("number2");
$number2.onkeydown = function(ev){
  console.log("tecla ingresada que debo validar" , ev.key)
  console.log("valor antes de la validacion" , this.value)
};
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Nivel de Seguridad"  min="65" max="90" id="number2">
```

**Con [Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**

```js
const $number2 = document.getElementById("number2");
$number2.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
   console.log("tecla ingresada que debo validar" , ev.key)
  console.log("valor antes de la validacion" , this.value)
 })
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Nivel de Seguridad"  min="65" max="90" id="number2">
```