# Llamar a una función desde otra función dentro de la misma clase javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Tengo una clase, en el constructor esta crea y agrega una lista de elementos al DOM, a la vez le asigna un evento *CLICK* a cada elemento(li). La función que ejecuta ese evento necesita acceder al elemento que disparó el evento, pero también a una de las propiedades de la clase, si uso *this* solo puedo acceder a una de esas dos cosas, me he creado una función en la clase que me permita acceder a la propiedad de la clase y desde la función del evento acceder al elemento que lo dispara para desde ahí llamar a la función que accede a la propiedad de la clase, pero no se como llamar a esa función, si uso *this* no va funcionar porque hace referencia al elemento que disparo el evento y si la intento llamar sin el, me presenta un error.

**clase.js**

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(_contenedor) {
        this.contenedor = _contenedor;
    }
    iniciar() {
        let html =
                    '<p>Seleccione algo</p>' +
                    '<ul>' +
                        '<li>Uno</li>' +
                        '<li>Dos</li>' +
                        '<li>Tres</li>' +
                    '</ul>';
        $(this.contenedor).append(html);
        $(this.contenedor + ' li').click(this.seleccionar_opcion);
    }
    seleccionar_opcion() {
        let op_texto = $(this).html();
        cambiar_opcion(op_texto);
    }
    cambiar_opcion(nueva_opcion) {
        $(this.contenedor + ' p').html(nueva_opcion);
    }
}

miscript.js
(function () {
    let prueba = new MyClass('#company-filter');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        prueba.iniciar();
    });
})();
```

Comment: Nombreclase.nombrefuncion();

Comment: Exactamente en qué parte de tu código intentas hacer eso? no me queda muy claro

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo crear eventos delegados en JavaScript puro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110972/c%c3%b3mo-crear-eventos-delegados-en-javascript-puro)

Answer (score 2):

Tambien puedes hacerlo creando otra variable para referirte a `this` asi:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(_contenedor) {
        this.contenedor = _contenedor;
    }
    iniciar() {
        let that = this;
        let html =
                    '<p>Seleccione algo</p>' +
                    '<ul>' +
                        '<li>Uno</li>' +
                        '<li>Dos</li>' +
                        '<li>Tres</li>' +
                    '</ul>';
        $(this.contenedor).append(html);
        $(this.contenedor + ' li').click(function() {
          let op_texto = $(this).html();
          $(that.contenedor + ' p').html(op_texto);
        });
    }
    
}


    let prueba = new MyClass('#company-filter');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        prueba.iniciar();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="company-filter"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

He logrado lo que necesitaba, asigne el evento con la función ***on*** esta permite agregar datos al llamado, en esos datos envío la propiedad de la clase que quería acceder.

```js
    class MyClass {
        constructor(_contenedor) {
            this.contenedor = _contenedor;
        }
        iniciar() {
            let html =
                        '<p>Seleccione algo</p>' +
                        '<ul>' +
                            '<li>Uno</li>' +
                            '<li>Dos</li>' +
                            '<li>Tres</li>' +
                        '</ul>';
            $(this.contenedor).append(html);
            $(this.contenedor).on('click', 'li', this.contenedor, this.seleccionar_opcion);
        }
        seleccionar_opcion(event) {
            let op_texto = $(this).html();
            $(event.data + ' p').html(op_texto);
        }
    }

    let prueba = new MyClass('#company-filter');
        $(document).ready(function () {
            prueba.iniciar();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="company-filter"></div>
```

Me eliminé la otra función también. . .

[Documentación](http://api.jquery.com/on/) evento `on`

> Delegated event handlers have the advantage that they can process
>   events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a
>   later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at
>   the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use
>   delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove
>   event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view
>   in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the
>   event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document.
>   The document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.
>
> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements
>   not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their
>   potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be
>   monitored. On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example
>   attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

> An event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one
>   element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level
>   (from the clicked tr to tbody):

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: Con tu permiso edito tu respuesta con algo más de información sobre los delegados en el evento "on" y añado el snippet con el código funcionando tal y como lo has puesto.

Comment: Excelente @Kiko_L