# Ejecutar un evento "Onclick" desde javascript en controles Dinamicos

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Tengo problemas con un formulario en ASP.net en VB, este formulario creo texbox dinámicos y tengo un botón para ir agregando los textbox.
Ahora este boton al agregar la nueva fila de textbox guarda lo que tenga una fila antes en la BD.
Ahora la pregunta es como puedo hacer para que al presionar el la tecla "Enter" ejecute el evento onclick de mi boton.
Intente con la propiedad DefaultButton pero solo funciona cuando se refresca la pagina, después de hacer click en otra parte de la interfaz deja de funcionar.
E visto que se puede reconocer cuando se presiona la tecla "Enter" desde javascript, pero no se como ejecutar el código del evento.

Ese es el codigo que tengo en el botton el nombre del evento es "AddTextBox" en el evento Onclick

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add and Save " 
OnClick="AddTextBox" />
```

Este seria el CodeBing que contiene este boton

```
Protected Sub AddTextBox(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'primer panel'
    Dim index As Integer = PNLNoNotes.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToList().Count + 1 'crea una lista que contendra los nombres de los txt dinamicos de panel 1
    Me.CreateTextBox("txtPnl1" & index) 'txtPnl1 es el nombre de los txt del panel 1
    For Each textBox As TextBox In PNLNoNotes.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        If (textBox.ID = "txtPnl1" + Convert.ToString(index)) Then
            textBox.Text = index
            algo = index
        End If
    Next
RecuperarDatos(index)
end sub
```

Ok ahora Necesito saber como puedo 1ro, detectar cuando se presiona la tecla "Enter" y segundo saber como mandar llamar o ejecutar este evento cuando se presione la tecla "Enter"

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo crear eventos delegados en JavaScript puro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110972/c%c3%b3mo-crear-eventos-delegados-en-javascript-puro)

Comment: Hola Jack, vi la pregunta y si es similar, pero el quiere crear controles con eventos, yo ya creo los controles, lo que necesito es que al presionar la tecla "Enter" ejecute un evento que ya tengo

Comment: puedes agregar un ejemplo

Comment: Jack edite  la pregunta y puse mi  código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres ejecutar el evento "click" de tu "boton" al presionar **enter** dentro de tu "textbox":

> Usando jQuery

```
$("#txtPnl1").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) // 13 es el keycode de "enter"
    {
        $("#btnAdd").trigger("click"); // ejecutas el evento click del boton
    }
})
```

> Usando javascript puro

```
document.querySelector("#txtPnl1").addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {    
     var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

     if (key == 13) { // 13 es keycode de 'enter'
         document.querySelector("#btnAdd").click(); // ejecutas el evento click del boton
     }
})
```

En ambos solo cambia el selector **#txtPnl1** si el id de tu textbox es otro, y el selector **#btnAdd** si el id de tu boton es otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias Erick, es justo lo que necesitaba, eso de JavaScript no es lo mio, muchas gracias me ayudaste bastanta

Comment: Alexis, que bueno saber que te sirvio mi respuesta. Saludos!