# ¿Para qué sirve el objeto EVENT?

Tags: javascript

No le encuentro sentido al objeto Event. Quizá sea porque tengo que traducir los artículos del inglés, y el traductor no lo hace bien. En el ejemplo de abajo: ¿por qué no simplemente la propiedad pageX me regresa el valor, es decir, por qué usar Event? No lo entiendo.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event){ 
  $("span").text("X: " + event.pageX + ", Y: " + event.pageY); 
});
```

Comment: lo que estas haciendo es agregar un evento, el valor event, tiene el contexto this a donde le diste click, [puedes leer mas en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110972/c%C3%B3mo-crear-eventos-delegados-en-javascript-puro)

Answer (score 2):

[Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event) es un objeto que tiene muchas propiedades y método tales como:

- `altKey`
- `bubbles`
- `clientX`
- `target`
- `pageX`
- `pageY`
- `preventDefault()`
- `stopPropagation()`

Y aparte de estas hay muchas mas.

Ahora te imaginas que todas esas propiedades se pasaran como parámetros en los eventos

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(altKey, bubbles, clientX, 
                           target, pageX, pageY, ...) {

});
```

La sintaxis seria realmente desastrosa y mantener el código se volvería imposible.

Y respondiendo a tu pregunta de porque el evento [mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) no tiene, solo, los parámetros como el evento `scrollTop`, es sencillo, ambos eventos no están destinados para el mismo propósito. El evento `scrollTop` no interactúa con el dom como lo hace el evento `mousemove`, por lo que no necesita de todas las propiedades y los métodos que tiene el parámetro event, del evento `mousemove`.

Answer (score 1):

- La variable `event` que se esta pasando como argumento a la función anónima, es para poder recuperar el resultado que arroja el evento usado; que en este caso es `mousemove` el cual detecta el la posición del *puntero del mouse* sobre la pantalla.
- Lo necesitas usar por que el método en JQuery llamado `pageX` y `pageY` van a regresarte un valor dependiendo de en que parte de la pantalla este evento se dispare.
- Si no haces esta sintaxis `event.pageX` y por el contrario solo haces:

  console.log(pageX)

Los resultados serán:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

Pues desconoce en que parte de la pantalla el evento `mousemove` recuperado por la variable `event` esta siendo ejecutado

**Ejemplo 1 con JS puro** (sin embargo el concepto sería el mismo)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
          console.log(event.screenX)
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

- Es importante mencionar también que como `mousemove` es un evento que ocurre, tiene métodos asociados; los cuales puedes ver si en tu código haces lo siguiente:

  console.log(event)

Que te devolvería algo similar a esto (es solo un extracto pues la información es amplia):

```
</body></html>, [circular object HTMLDocument], [circular object Window]],
  preventDefault: function preventDefault() { [native code] },
  relatedTarget: null,
  returnValue: true,
  screenX: 925,
  screenY: 172,
  shiftKey: false,
  sourceCapabilities: [object InputDeviceCapabilities] {
    firesTouchEvents: false
  },
```

Comment: Hola gracias por toda al explicacion pero la verdad sigo sin entender. Porque por ejemplo yo podria hacer lo mismo con mouseover y ademas scrollTop y no necesitaria de usar "event"...lo que no entiendo es porque para este caso si y para sroll no.