# Seleccionar div que no esta en el DOM

Tags: html, jquery

quiero seleccionar el div padre para cambiar el texto de un boton.

pero resulta que este div solo aparece si se da clic en un botón, es decir al cargar la pagina el div no existe entonces no lo puedo seleccionar.

tengo entendido que para seleccionar es de la siguiente forma.

```
<div id="div">
    <button class="close">s</button>
</div>

$("#div button.close").html("X");
```

Gracias.

Comment: Para este caso debes aplicar la delegación de eventos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo crear eventos delegados en JavaScript puro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110972/c%c3%b3mo-crear-eventos-delegados-en-javascript-puro)

Answer (score 0):

La función de cambiar el texto debe ser llamada cuando se da click en el botón que carga el contenido.

```js
var my_contador = 8
var my_interval;

function mostrar(){
  $('#padre').append('<button id="close" onclick="cerrar()">Cerrar</button>')
  contadorCerrar();
}

function contadorCerrar(){
  my_contador = 8
  my_interval = setInterval(cambiarTexto(),1000)
  setTimeout(cerrar(), 1000 * my_contador)
}

function cambiarTexto(){
    my_contador -= 1
    console.log(my_contador)
    //$('#close').text('Cerrar en '+my_contador+".")
}

function cerrar(){
   $('#padre').html("")
   //clearInterval(my_interval)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostar</button>
<div id="padre">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es verdad lo que mencionas, no puedes seleccionar un div que aun no existe,a menos que lo crees dinamicamente cada ves que lo necesites, y es correcta tu forma de cambiar el texto en el botón.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#btnTest").on("click",function(){
              var sHtml = '<div id="div"><button class="close">s</button></div>';
              $("#showDiv").html(sHtml);
              $("#div button.close").html("X");
          })
          $("#btnChangeLetter").on("click",function(){
            $("#div button.close").html("AS");
          })
        
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="btnTest">crear</a>

  <a href="#" id="btnChangeLetter">cambiar letra</a>
  <div id="showDiv"></div>
```