# Selector jquery no selecciona div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy intentando lanzar una función dando click a un div de la siguiente forma

```js
$(".project-task").click(function() {
        console.log("adsf");
    });
```

```html
<div class="card-columns task-columns">
  <div class="card project-task" code="1"></div>
</div>
```

Decir que el `div` con la clase `project-task` se genera mediante `ajax` cuando hago click en otro `div`, por lo que puede ser este el problema

Si cambio la clase a la que apunta a una que no se genere mediante ajax como esta `$(".task-columns").click()` si que funciona

Hay que *'recargar'* de alguna manera `js` para que busque los elementos del `DOM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Nota:** Esta propuesta se basa enteramente en JS, pero la idea de solución debe poder ser transportable a la biblioteca de *JQuery*

Este elemento con la clase `.project-task` se genera de forma dinámica, por lo tanto deberás delegar el evento del click a una etiqueta superior o padre que ya exista dentro del DOM.

Como ya tienes un `div` superior podemos tomar el *evento click* de este mismo y posterior vigilar si quien disparó el evento tiene la clase del elemento dinámico generado.

**Propuesta**

Obtenemos primero al elemento padre y lo asignamos a una variable

```
let divPadre = document.querySelector(".card-columns")
```

Posterior le damos un *listener* en el evento click

```
divPadre.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {

})
```

Ahora dentro del cuerpo de la *arrow function* podemos evaluar precisamente si el elemento que disparó el *evento* contiene la clase deseada

```
divPadre.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
    if (evento.target.classList.contains(".project-task")) {
        /*acciones que le darás*/
    }
})
```

Dentro de la función evaluamos con un *condicional simple* para que en caso de que el elemento que generó el click contenga la clase, entonces generamos acciones en concecuencia.

**Enlaces de referencia y lecturas de ayuda**

- [Delegación de eventos](https://ed.team/blog/como-usar-la-delegacion-de-eventos-en-javascript)
- [Recursos sobre delegación de eventos en JS puro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110972/c%C3%B3mo-crear-eventos-delegados-en-javascript-puro)