# Problema al eliminar manejador de eventos con jQuery - función .off()

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código, he usado el método `.on()` de `jQuery` porque los elementos con clase `.grid-letra` se crean de manera dinámica.

```
$('#abecedario').on('click', '.grid-letra', function() {
    $(this).off();

    // instrucciones
});
```

Quiero que solo se ejecute una vez, por eso intento quitar el manejador de eventos en la función manejadora, pero se quita.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal si simplemente agregas otra clase y agregas el click a los elementos con esa clase, y cuando haces click, eliminas la clase y listo, el click no funcionara:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
   $("#contenido").append("<button class='dinamico click'>Elemento dinamico</button><br>");
});

$("#contenido").on("click", ".click", function(){
      $(this).removeClass('click'); 
      alert('elemento clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>agregar</button>
<div id="contenido"></div>
```

La razon por la que a ti no te funciona es porque `on()` se aprovecha del bubbling o capture de los evento, por lo que el evento no es agregado directamente a los elementos del selector, sino que son registrados en memoria y cuando hagas click jquery busca los elementos registrados y ejecuta el click si el `event.target` fue registrado.

Dale una mirada a esta pregunta en caso de que no sepas que es bubbling y capturing: [Diferencia entre Bubbling y Capturing](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105687/diferencia-entre-bubbling-y-capturing)

Comment: Lo probaré.

Lo que me extraña es que si en otro lugar del script hago esto:
   $('#abecedario').off('click', '.grid-letra');
Sí que elimina el manejador a todos los elementos.